# gpg: can't check signature: No public key, even after importing public key

Tags: gnupg

I am new to encryption and tried to work with it today. I managed to sign the file, encrypt it, and decrypt it on my other computer. However, whenever I try to verify the file, I get the error:

```
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I have imported the sender's public key to the receiver, but I still get the error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Verify Putty Download with GPG CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390615/how-to-verify-putty-download-with-gpg-cli)

Comment: That post was about a different older key, which is a different situation I think.